# Free-as-in-freedom version of APNS / FCM

Tags: open-source, firebase

Is there a free-as-in-freedom version of Apple Push Notification service or Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)? It doesn't need to be able to send to iOS apps or Android apps necessarily. It would be useful for any apps running anywhere, including desktop linux, Phosh, or Plasma Mobile.